# Get all first four digit values within a column of data and make those values a new column of data in R

Tags: r, dataset

I'm having trouble separating values within a column. Let's assume we have:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 123456 |
| 2 | B | 789101 |
| 3 | C | 112131 |
| 4 | D | 415161 |

I'm trying to get the first four numbers from all the values from Column C and get all the new values into a new within the dataset like so:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 123456 | 1234 |
| 2 | B | 789101 | 7891 |
| 3 | C | 112131 | 1121 |
| 4 | D | 415161 | 4151 |

How would I go about doing this in R

I've tried using:

```
df$columnd = substr(columnc, 1, 4)
```

This doesn't seem to work. The other thing is that I want it not to be attached to the same dataset. I want it all to be attached to a different variable. I'm not sure if that made any sense.

Comment: *"I want it not to be attached to the same dataset"* You've got your `df$` backwards then. `columnc` is a column of your data (presumably named `df`), so you need to use `df$columnc` to find it. However you say you **don't** want the result `columnd` to be part of `df`, so **don't** use `df$` before it. `columnd = substr(df$columnc, 1, 4)` should work and `columnd` won't have any connection with `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Correction in your code:

add `df$`there

`df$columnd <- substr(df$columnc, 1, 4)`